# Include some categorical variable cases in scatterplot, while excluding others

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to teach myself some R, by playing with RStudio and making graphs with data from the latest season of the NBA. There is some duplicate player data, some of which I would like to include, and some of which I would like to exclude, in some graphs.

My data set comes from https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_game.html (I don't know how to directly link to the CSV data, but it is available under the "Share & More" menu item). After downloading the stats to a file, I import it into RStudio...

```
> stats <- read.csv("~/Downloads/2018-2019 NBA per game stats.txt")
```

I make a sample scatterplot...

```
> ggplot(stats, aes(x=MP,y=FGA)) +geom_point()
```

But I notice, there are a number of points that are duplicates for players, because they got traded and played for multiple teams in the year. For example, there's Ryan Anderson and Trevor Ariza...

```
Player                    Tm     MP     FGA
Ryan Anderson\anderry01   TOT    322    69
Ryan Anderson\anderry01   PHO    278    60
Ryan Anderson\anderry01   MIA    44     9
OG Anunoby\anunoog01      TOR    1352   404
Trevor Ariza\arizatr01    TOT    2349   736
Trevor Ariza\arizatr01    PHO    884    227
Trevor Ariza\arizatr01    WAS    1465   509
```

How do I create a scatterplot that includes players who played for only 1 team (like OG Anunoby), or for players' total year statistics (Ryan Anderson and Trevor Ariza's TOT line), but not their partial seasons (Ryan Anderson and Trevor Ariza's PHO, MIA, and WAS lines)?

I imagine there is a way to use some `ifelse` statement
to create a dummy variable, or pass that information onto `ggplot` or `geom_point`, but I am struggling to find other examples of something like that online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To create a scatterplot that includes players who played for only 1 team (like OG Anunoby):

```
library(tidyverse)

# first, identify which players play for more than 1 team. 

single_team_players <- stats %>%
select(Player) %>%
group_by(Player) %>%
# counts how many teams a player has played for
summarise(count = n()) %>%
# keep only players that have played for 1 team
filter(count == 1)

# then filter out these players from stats
stats_single_team_players <- stats %>%
filter(Player %in% single_team_players$Player)

# create scatterplot
ggplot(stats_single_team_players, aes(x=MP,y=FGA))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title = "Single Team Players")
```

2) To create a scatterplot for players' total year statistics (Ryan Anderson and Trevor Ariza's TOT line), but not their partial seasons (Ryan Anderson and Trevor Ariza's PHO, MIA, and WAS lines)

```
# filter for single team players OR team = TOT
total_year_stats <- stats %>%
  filter((Player %in% single_team_players$Player)|
           (Tm == "TOT"))

# graph scatterplot
ggplot(total_year_stats, aes(x=MP,y=FGA)) +
  geom_point()+
  labs(title = "Total Year Stats")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will look at it further.

Comment: OH, it took me a minute to figure out what you were doing here, in making a new data.frame (I think that's the right terminology) of "total_year_stats" at the end of it. That makes a couple of other things I wanted to do later, easier. Cool deal!

Comment: Glad it helps! 

I like to err on the side of making more dataframes / objects. Sometimes it can make projects easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding indicator columns with `ave` (inline count aggregate) and `ifelse` (conditional logic) to be used to `subset` main data according to needed plots:

```
# NEW COLUMNS
stats$team_count <- with(stats, ave(MP, Player, FUN=length))
stats$tot_indicator <- with(stats, ifelse(team_count == 1, 'TOT', Tm))

# SUBSETTED DATA SCATTERPLOT (ONE TEAM PLAYERS)
ggplot(subset(stats, team_count == 1), aes(x=MP, y=FGA)) + geom_point() 

# SUBSETTED DATA SCATTERPLOT (ALL PLAYERS' TOT)
ggplot(subset(stats, tot_indicator == 'TOT'), aes(x=MP, y=FGA)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had a few errors initially, in creating the columns: 
 ```Error in ifelse(team_count == 1, "TOT", Tm) : object 'Tm' not found```  but once I got more specific (```stats$team_count <- with(stats, ave(MP, Player, FUN=length))  
stats$tot_indicator <- ifelse(team_count == 1, 'TOT', Tm)``` then I got the results I wanted.

Comment: Whoops, my awful overlook! Forgot the `stats$` qualifier and `with()` See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "TOT" with `filter` and then use `group_by` and `summarize`.  You can then use `ggplot` on the resulting dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

read_table("Player                    Tm     MP     FGA
Ryan Anderson\anderry01   TOT    322    69
Ryan Anderson\anderry01   PHO    278    60
Ryan Anderson\anderry01   MIA    44     9
OG Anunoby\anunoog01      TOR    1352   404
Trevor Ariza\arizatr01    TOT    2349   736
Trevor Ariza\arizatr01    PHO    884    227
Trevor Ariza\arizatr01    WAS    1465   509") -> data

data %>%
filter(TM != "TOT") %>%
group_by(Player) %>%
summarize(MP = sum(MP), FGA = sum(FGA))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Player                       MP   FGA
  <chr>                     <dbl> <dbl>
1 "OG Anunoby\anunoog01"     1352   404
2 "Ryan Anderson\anderry01"   322    69
3 "Trevor Ariza\arizatr01"   2349   736
```

`distinct` would also work here so long as "TOT" is always before the actual teams:

```
data %>%
distinct(Player, .keep_all = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Player                    Tm       MP   FGA
  <chr>                     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 "Ryan Anderson\anderry01" TOT     322    69
2 "OG Anunoby\anunoog01"    TOR    1352   404
3 "Trevor Ariza\arizatr01"  TOT    2349   736
```

Also, if you want to work basketball reference data, check out the `ballr` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ballr/index.html) which provides an api for interacting with basketballreference.com.

Comment: This answer counts the TOT values twice. Ariza didn't actually play 4698 minutes; that would be an average of 47 min per game over a 100-game season, and the NBA season has 82 games with each game at 48 minutes.

Comment: @mmyoung77 That's right, of course! Just updated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions to examine, and the aptly-named ```ballr``` package. :-)